# Which JRadioButton selected

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I have several JRadioButtons in a ButtonGroup.

```
   private ButtonGroup radioGroup= new ButtonGroup();
   private JRadioButton radio1= new JRadioButton("Red");
   private JRadioButton radio2= new JRadioButton("Green");
   private JRadioButton radio3= new JRadioButton("Blue");

   radioGroup.add(radio1);
   radioGroup.add(radio2);
   radioGroup.add(radio3);
```

How can I check which one was selected?
 
With `System.out.println(radioGroup.getSelection())` I only get something like `javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel@32b3714`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the selected ButtonModel, you can get the actionCommand String (if you remember to set it!).

```
// code not compiled, run, nor tested in any way
ButtonModel model = radioGroup.getSelection();
String actionCommand = (model == null) ? "" : model.getActionCommand():
System.out.println(actionCommand);
```

But this will only work if you set the actionCommand first. e.g.,:

```
// code not compiled, run, nor tested in any way
String[] colors = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
JRadioButton[] radioBtns = new JRadioButton[colors.length];
for (int i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
   radioBtns[i] = new JRadioButton(colors[i]);
   radioBtns[i].setActionCommand(colors[i]);
   radioGroup.add(radioBtns[i]);
   somePanel.add(radioBtns[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the default implementation of the `toString` method. And `ButtonGroup#getSelection` will return the `ButtonModel` of the selected `JRadioButton`.

See also [How do I get which JRadioButton is selected from a ButtonGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201287/how-do-i-get-which-jradiobutton-is-selected-from-a-buttongroup).

Answer (score 3):

If listeners are attached, an easy way to determine the source is to call [`ActionEvent.getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29).

Comment: +1 but from Darryl's [Select Button Group](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/09/select-button-group/), EDIT this man is really an alien, implemented custom finalize(), bump ...

Comment: @mKorbel  I wish I saw more (or any, for that matter) of Darryl around these parts.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the text of selected radiobutton from buttongroup

```
    Enumeration<AbstractButton> allRadioButton=radioGroup.getElements();  
    while(allRadioButton.hasMoreElements())  
    {  
       JRadioButton temp=(JRadioButton)allRadioButton.nextElement();  
       if(temp.isSelected())  
       {  
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You select : "+temp.getText());  
       }  
    }
```