# How to find that item is selected in a button group?

Tags: java, swing, buttongroup

In Java swing, I want to be able to tell what item is selected in a button group. I looked in the Button Group API and didn't see anything that would achieve this. Is there some method that any of you have discovered to do this?

Comment: [`group.getSelectedItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#getSelection()) isnt working for you?

Comment: that just returns the Button model and doesn't allow me to interact with the selected button.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you'd want your program to work. If you want something to happen as soon as something is selected, then you should be using a listener. I don't think you're understanding the concept of `ButtonGroup`. The documentation says "creates a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of buttons". This object's goal (the group object) is to take the buttons you add to it, and ensure that only one is selected at a time. If you told us what you're trying to actually do, we could help quickee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference [ButtonGroup: getSelection()](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/ButtonGroupgetSelection.htm)

The following example shows how to manage the selection of an item in a button group:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JRadioButton dem = new JRadioButton("Bill", false);
    dem.setActionCommand("Bill");
    JRadioButton rep = new JRadioButton("Bob", false);
    rep.setActionCommand("Bob");
    JRadioButton ind = new JRadioButton("Ross", false);
    ind.setActionCommand("Ross");

    final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(dem);
    group.add(rep);
    group.add(ind);

    class VoteActionListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ex) {
        String choice = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();
        System.out.println("ACTION Candidate Selected: " + choice);
      }
    }

    class VoteItemListener implements ItemListener {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ex) {
        String item = ((AbstractButton) ex.getItemSelectable()).getActionCommand();
        boolean selected = (ex.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
        System.out.println("ITEM Candidate Selected: " + selected + " Selection: " + item);
      }
    }

    ActionListener al = new VoteActionListener();
    dem.addActionListener(al);
    rep.addActionListener(al);
    ind.addActionListener(al);

    ItemListener il = new VoteItemListener();
    dem.addItemListener(il);
    rep.addItemListener(il);
    ind.addItemListener(il);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    c.add(new JLabel("Please Cast Your Vote"));
    c.add(dem);
    c.add(rep);
    c.add(ind);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

See the Java Tutorial [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> I would just loop through your JRadioButtons and call isSelected(). If you really want to go from the ButtonGroup you can only get to the models. You could match the models to the buttons, but then if you have access to the buttons, why not use them directly?

quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201287/how-do-i-get-which-jradiobutton-is-selected-from-a-buttongroup)

If you are using actions at the end, it would also be helpful to set an action for each button then:

```
buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
...
...
button1.setActionCommand("Java");
...
buttonGroup.add(button1);
...

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Selected Button: " + buttonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand());
}
```