# How can I get an Object's name in java

Tags: java

I have a group of radio buttons that doesn't includes any text on frame 1.

Every button has a `j` label `l`, which means that when I choose one radio button, I want to change the icon of a specific `j` label.

I want to know which button is selected to send it to frame 2 by a constructor.

So I want send the variable of the current radio button that's clicked.

How can i do that?

```
public String getSelectedButtonText(ButtonGroup buttonGroup) {
    for (
        Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = buttonGroup.getElements();
        buttons.hasMoreElements();
    ) {
        AbstractButton button = buttons.nextElement();

        if (button.isSelected()) {
            return button.getText();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What's the question here? You seem to have done it.

Answer (score 0):

```
JRadioButton radioA = new JRadioButton(0);
JRadioButton radioB = new JRadioButton(0);
ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
buttonGroup.add(radioA);
buttonGroup.add(radioB);

JLabel label = new JLabel("The label");
```

When you click the button to go to the next frame....

```
if(radioA.isSelected()) {
  label.setText("Radio A is Selected");
  gotoNextFrame();
}
else if(radioB.isSelected()) {
  label.setText("Radio B is Selected");
  gotoNextFrame();
}
```

More - [How do I get which JRadioButton is selected from a ButtonGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201287/how-do-i-get-which-jradiobutton-is-selected-from-a-buttongroup)