# Getting the name assigned to a JComponent

Tags: java, swing

I have an arrayList with a varying amount of names in the Array depending on how its used. I create JRadioButtons for one of the functions with the name of the arrayList such like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < m_fixtures.size(); i++){
    panel.add(new JRadioButton(m_fixtures.get(i)));
}
```

Is there any way I can check what name has been assigned to that JRadioButton as i want to do something along the lines of

get the selected Jradiobuttons "label" and add do something to that data but I cannot figure out how to get the "label" assigned to it.

Comment: Have you tried invoking getText()?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201287/how-do-i-get-which-jradiobutton-is-selected-from-a-buttongroup

Comment: @RubioRic but the buttons dont have a specific identifier such as JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("text");
I dont know how to call .getText() on a butotn that doesn't have an instance name.

Comment: @PigeonMilkStories Maybe my answer helps

Answer (score 2):

```
   Component[] components = panel.getComponents();

   for (Component singleComponent : components) {
       if (singleComponent instanceof JRadioButton) {
           JRadioButton jrb = (JRadioButton) singleComponent;
           // println or whatever you want
           System.out.println(jrb.getText());
       }
   }
```