# Why is my second JButton not visible on the JFrame in Java swing code?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Second button (b2) is not visible on the JFrame.

All the 3 componenets l1,l2 and b2 are visible on JFrame but JButton b2 isn't.

```
        public void Joptionpane(int a)
        {
        l1=new JLabel("Your score is :" + a);
        l2=new JLabel("Do you want to continue ?");
        b1= new JButton("Yes");
        b2= new JButton("NO");


        add(l1);
        add(l2);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);

       l1.setBounds(150,10,400,50);
       l2.setBounds(150,60,400,50);
       b1.setBounds(200,130,100,50);
       b2.setBounds(300,130,100,50);
```

I have set the Layout to null

```
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Flappy Bird");
        setSize(700,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Don't use null layouts and `setBounds`. Learn and use the layout managers

Comment: When you ask a question post a proper [mre].

Comment: A score notification should be a `JOptionPane` rather than a `JFrame` itself. And if that's the case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904362/multiple-joptionpane-input-dialogs/41904856#41904856) on the `singleDialogInformation` part might be of help

Answer (score 2):

From the code, it seems the app. needs something like this:

[image]

That is a `JOptionPane`, which is well suited to the task, as opposed to a `JFrame`, which isn't.

The code for that follows:

```
String text = "<html><p>Your score is: 42."
        + "<p>Do you want to continue?";
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, text, "Flappy Bird", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (result==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Continue!");
    // TODO! Start another game
} else {
    System.out.println("Exit!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> ```
>     setVisible(true);
>     setLayout(null);
> ```

Perhaps you should set the layout to null before you tell the frame to draw everything ...

And as we are on it: set the size before making the panel visible, too.

Sorry, but that are all no brainers. You can not fry an egg in the pan before you break the shell, but that is what you are doing.

> ```
>     setLayout(null);
>     setSize(700,300);
>     setVisible(true);
> ```

Comment: *"Perhaps you should set the layout to null.."* No matter what comes after that, it's poor advice.

Comment: Never, never suggest null layouts when far better options exist.

Comment: Options like as noted in @AndrewThompson's answer

Comment: I did not suggest a null layout. He is using one. And setting a layout to null after you have placed panels on the parent panel makes no sense.