# Receive the result of radio group button selection from confirmed JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I have made a panel which contains two radio groups of buttons. You can find the result of `JPanel` in the image below. Then I used the below code to add this panel to a `JOptionPane` box:

```
OptionsForDisjunctionNodes optionsForDisjunctionNodes=new  OptionsForDisjunctionNodes();
JPanel p=optionsForDisjunctionNodes.getPanel();
int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Decision on Disjunctive Nodes", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == option) {
    // Print selected radio button in each group. How?
} else {
    // Do something else. 
}
```

Let's say the name of group boxes are `buttonGroup1`, and `buttonGroup2`

I need to when the user click on **Ok button**, **I print the selected label in both groups**

[image]

Comment: A lost of the answer depends on the design of `OptionsForDisjunctionNodes`. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The `OptionsForDisjunctionNodes` is a `JPanel` which contains 2 `groupBox`

Comment: An MCVE / SSCCE is code, not a (poor) textual explanation. And while I remember: see also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) (Alt+PrintScreen on Windows is your friend.)

Answer (score -1):

Let OptionsForDisjunctionNodes add a listener to the radio buttons. And when pressed have it store whatever option was pressed last.

Then also provide getters on OptionsForDisjunctionNodes to retrieve this information.

---

Alternatively, you still provide getters in OptionsForDisjunctionNodes but have them loop over the button group to find which option is selected.

Check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201287/how-do-i-get-which-jradiobutton-is-selected-from-a-buttongroup) for ideas on how to do that exactly.

Answer (score -1):

You could work with action commands on the `JRadioButtons` like this:

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroup1=new ButtonGroup();
JRadioButton r1=new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton r2=new JRadioButton();
r1.setActionCommand("hello");

buttonGroup1.add(r1);
buttonGroup1.add(r2);
```

your if would then look like this:

```
if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == option) {
    System.out.println(buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand());
    System.out.println(buttonGroup2.getSelection().getActionCommand());
} else {

}
```

for `buttonGroup1` it would print hello in this case if r1 is selected

Comment: I would like to try the second solution, but it complains with `cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable buttonGroup1`

Comment: @Salman can you show full code? i think its out of scope, but can't tell for sure